# Why does the following modulo division give 78 instead of 0?

Tags: r, modulo

I have a strange occurrence and I don't understand the answer given to me, maybe I'm misunderstanding the answer.. I'm coding with R :

```
 x <- 2929530240
 x/169 # 17334498
 x%%169  # 78
```

Why is it 78 instead of 0 ?

Comment: and what would `y` be?

Comment: Just noticed that x/169 is not a round number but R returns it as such.

Comment: Oh sorry, y <- 169 but it wasn't needed in my example.

Comment: So on my calculator, x/169 = 17334498.46 whereas on R I get 17334498, so why does R remove the .46 ?

Comment: @MadanDaniel ;  `print(x/169, digits=20)`

Comment: Thank you @user20650 but now I noticed that the problem lies not with modulo but with the removal of decimal places and I'm wondering about this issue.

Comment: If you don't want to manually do that each time you can also change your base options: `options(digits = 20)`

Comment: Thank you everyone, I didn't know that options$digits is set to 7 by default and this explains the answer.

Comment: @MadanDaniel ; do note that using the digits option is only to change how it is printed in the r terminal, the object stays the same.

Comment: Got it @user20650 . Thanks ! I'm new to Stack Overflow, how can I report the question has been answered ?

Comment: @MadanDaniel ; if you have an answer you are happy with, you are encouraged to add an answer yourself https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . You can then mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all for your insightful answers, so the issue lied with the default options$digits value which is set to 7.

So that's why the result of my division was not showing the remaining digits.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out! You can now mark this answer as "Accepted" by clicking the little check mark near the up/down arrows.